# How to get Word to repeat a Heading?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a Word document using MS Word for Mac version 15.22.1 (2016).

My document uses the `Heading X` styles.

If content below a heading spills on to another page, I would like Word to add the heading text to the next page above the content.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick. You'll write each section in your document in a **table of two rows**, the first row has the text in `Heading (X)`, and the second one contains its body text. Place the caret in the first row of a table and from the Ribbon tab `Layout`, grouped under `Data`, enable the `Repeat Header Rows`. Finally, set the table's borders to `No Border` so it will look as regular as any text.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the top of the Word, it should open up an editable region which contains the header contents as well as footer (if you scroll to bottom of the page). Whatever you put in there will be repeated to any number of pages you open.

More info about it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-headers-and-footers-f22334fb-4455-4b18-9354-7c9c70c3b032?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but your answer does not address my question.

Comment: Heading vs. Header.  But if the question was about headers, you would probably want to talk about using section breaks to control the range, since the question is about specific pages rather than the entire document.